# import and update drupal webform submission from remote url

Tags: 7, webforms, services

Is it possible to retrieve data from a remote server, pass it to a  Drupal site, and if the corresponding webform is present, to update these values in the database, else, create a new webform submission based on these retrieved data?

1) What modules will I need to do so if it is possible?
2) Any sample codes present already which can help me proceed?

Thanks...

Comment: What do you need the webform for? Can't you just retrieve the data from a remote server into Drupal, check if certain value is in the DB and do something based on that?

Comment: The fact is, another team will be pushing this data via a URL to my drupal site, and I need to capture these and then do the needful on the mysql db for this drupal site.